# Unable to add to cart on my website. Some Javascript Bug?

Tags: javascript, themes, shopify, e-commerce

I am using this theme for my personal project. My support has expired and theme developer doesn't really care to respond.

The problem is, if a product has a variable, it's not letting me select the variation and add it to the cart. The button remains ***disabled***.

There's definitely some problem with javascript if I were to take a wild guess.
How do I fix it?

Example Link: https://click-demo.myshopify.com/products/basic-swear-shirt

Comment: Looks to me that a lot of things need fixing. I recommend just following this [tutorial](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-pages-Add-color-swatches-to-products/td-p/616427) and changing the variant selection, buy now button, etc. **Make sure to duplicate your theme first**

Comment: I think you need to update some liquid code, to make it working and need some good knowledge of liquid code and Shopify theme structure.